# How can I replace text in PDF using Sjeda?

Tags: java, sejda

I need to replace a specific text or tags in a PDF file and save it.
I tried, iText, PDFBox and other libraries, but nothing works correctly.
Currently am going to use Sejda SDK but I cannot find the code which actually does the replacement.
They have this functionality working in the Desktop app. and in the web app. but I have to dig in the code to find it.

Can any one help please? and thanx in advance.

Comment: see also this link, "Why was the ReplaceText example removed?": https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/migration.html#why-was-the-replacetext-example-removed

Comment: I did see all issues related to text replacement, but I cannot convince my boss that its not a good thing to do. But I sow that Sejda had the exact functionality I needed.
Any way thank you.

Answer (score 1):

That is not part of the open source SDK.

Comment: Thank you Edi
Can you please point me to what to do? Do I have a chance to use the functionality at all? Is it part of the Pro version?
I mean there is nowhere to apply this functionality anywhere, whoever created this in your team is 100% the man.